# Function that builds dictionary based on lambda params

Tags: c#, functional-programming, reflection

I've written a method in c# that allows me to do create a dictionary from a passed in object and N lambda expressions that reference that objects properties and methods. It's working the way I want it and seems to perform well, but I'm looking for criticism and seeking to improve the code.

Here's an example usage:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }        

    public Dictionary<string, object> MakeDictionary()
    {
        return DictionaryThing.Data(this, x => x.Name, x => x.Age);             

        /* example return dictionary:

          Name: "Ronnie"
          Age: 29

        */
    }
}
```

And here's the code for DictionaryThing:

```
static class DictionaryThing 
{

    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Delegate> expCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Delegate>();

    public static Dictionary<string, object> Data<T>(T obj, params Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>[] expressions)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var exp in expressions)
        {
            string name = null;
            var body = exp.Body;    

            var unaryExp = body as UnaryExpression;
            if (unaryExp != null)
                body = unaryExp.Operand;

            var memberExp = body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExp != null)
                name = memberExp.Member.Name;

            var methodCallExp = body as MethodCallExpression;
            if (methodCallExp != null)
                name = methodCallExp.Method.Name;

            if (name == null)
                throw new InvalidExpressionException(
                    string.Format("The expression '{0}' is invalid. You must supply an expression that references a property or a function of the type '{1}'.",
                        exp.Body, typeof(T)));

            var key = typeof(T).FullName + "." + name;          
            var func = (Func<T, dynamic>)expCache.GetOrAdd(key, k => ((LambdaExpression)exp).Compile());

            dict[name] = func(obj);
        }

        return dict;
    }

}
```

My concerns are:

- Is there a better way to work with the expressions that are passed in.
- Can the expressions parameter be better constrained by a more appropriate type?
- Is there a better way to derive the cache key?

Answer (score 5):

Ronnie,

You have a good starting point for the problem you are trying to solve.

To answer your concerns:

1. Is there a better way to work with the expressions that are passed in.

   I think what you have done is fine. You are using Expression to let user specify methods/properties in type safe way. The only thing I would change is to use `Expression<Func<T, object>>[]` instead of `Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>[]` as dynamic will invoke the compiler at run time.
2. Can the expressions parameter be better constrained by a more appropriate type?

   I don't think you can specify additional constraints at compile time but you can definitely add code to validate the expression at runtime.
3. Is there a better way to derive the cache key?

   I think your cache key is fine. If you want to be more conservative, you can include Type.AssemblyQualifiedName. I would worry about it only if I was releasing to general public and not if I am using this class as part of a team.

With that said, here's the full re-factored code along with my notes. I hope it helps.

```
void Main()
{
    var ronnie = new Person();
    ronnie.Name = "Ronnie";
    ronnie.Address = "Greensboro, NC";
    
    var dictionary = ObjectToDictionaryConverter.GetDictionary(ronnie, x => x.Name, x => x.Address);
    
    // In following example, we are trying to pass in an expression which is not valid for our object.
    // Running this code will throw an appropriate exception like
    // Expression value(UserQuery+<>c__DisplayClass0).anotherDictionary.Keys is invalid. 
    // Expression Property/Member Type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
    //, expecting Type: UserQuery+Person
    
    //var anotherDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //var dictionary = ObjectToDictionaryConverter.GetDictionary(ronnie, x => anotherDictionary.Keys);    

    //I don't think you can enforce this constraint at compile time (I am not sure about it, I would love to be proved wrong.)
    
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary["Name"]); //Prints Ronnie
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary["Address"]); //Prints Greensboro, NC
    
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

// Why would you name a class like 'DictionaryThing'? It doesn't explain anything about what the class does. 
// Let's give it a more descriptive 'ObjectToDictionaryConverter' name. You may prefer some other name but 
// make sure that you put same thought in to naming your class as the code which goes inside the class.

// Next, the original code was doing two things
// 1. Inspecting the expression to derive a key
// 2. Create the dictionary from the input object (while also catching the expression details)

// Following SRP, let's separate it out in two classes so that each class is responsible for doing one thing.
// This also means that you can use the Expression inspection code somewhere else if you choose to.
public static class ObjectToDictionaryConverter 
{
    //Always spell out the variable name in its full. (expCache -> expressionCache)
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Delegate> expressionCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Delegate>();

    public static Dictionary<string, object> GetDictionary<T>(T obj, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expressions)
    {
        //Always validate your arguments. 
        if(ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            
        if(expressions.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("You must specify at least one expression.");
            
        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            if(expression == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("You can not specify NULL expression.");
        }
            
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        
        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            //The purpose of ExpressionDetail is to inspect our expression 
            var expressionDetail = ExpressionDetail.Create(expression);

            //A lambda expression can be a valid expression referring to a property or function.
            //But for our need, we will need to compile this expression to a delegate and run on object of Type T, let's make
            //sure that expression refers to the correct type.
            
            //IMPORTANT: We should not put this check in ExpressionDetail class. It is not
            //the responsibility of ExpressionDetail to enforce this type constraint. 
            //This type constraint is only needed for ObjectToDictionaryConverter class. 
            if(expressionDetail.DeclaringType != typeof(T))
                throw new InvalidExpressionException("Expression " + expression.Body + " is invalid. Expression Property/Member Type " + expressionDetail.DeclaringType.FullName + ", expecting Type: " + typeof(T).FullName);        
            
            //expressionDetail has properties like 'Name', 'FullName', 'Delegate' 
            var func = (Func<T, object>) expressionCache.GetOrAdd(expressionDetail.FullName, expressionDetail.Delegate);        
        
            result[expressionDetail.Name] = func(obj);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class ExpressionDetail
{
    private ExpressionDetail()
    {
    
    }
    
    public MemberInfo MemberInfo { get; private set; }
    
    public LambdaExpression Expression { get; private set; }
    
    //By figuring out MemberInfo from the Expression, 
    //we can now have all these read-only properties to get expression detail.
    public string Name { get { return MemberInfo.Name; } }
    
    public Type DeclaringType { get { return MemberInfo.DeclaringType; } }
    
    public string FullName { get { return DeclaringType.FullName + "." + Name; } }
    
    //Depending on performance requirement, you may want to use Lazy<T> to calculate this value
    //only once. 
    public Delegate Delegate { get { return Expression.Compile(); } }

    //We are expecting a lambda expression which should either point to a method or a property access.
    //To get body, we have to handle the case of expression being UnaryExpression
    //To learn more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567857/why-are-some-object-properties-unaryexpression-and-others-memberexpression
    private static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        //We don't validate arguments here only because it's a private method.
    
        var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        return unaryExpression != null ? unaryExpression.Operand : expression.Body;
    }
    
    //In your original method, you returned the name.
    //However, it could be even more useful to get the MemberInfo and store it.
    //Now we will have access to Name as well as the Type in which the property/method is declared.

    // There are lots of edge cases here. 
    // Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression and update this method to handle the edge cases that you care about.
    private static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(Expression expression)
    {
        //We don't validate arguments here only because it's a private method.
        
        var memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;
        
        if(memberExpression != null)
            return memberExpression.Member;
            
        var methodCallExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;
        
        if(methodCallExpression != null)
            return methodCallExpression.Method;
            
        return null;
    }
    
    public static ExpressionDetail Create(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        if(expression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
            
        var body = GetBody(expression);
        
        var memberInfo = GetMemberInfo(body);
        
        if (memberInfo == null)
                throw new InvalidExpressionException(
                    string.Format("The expression '{0}' is invalid. You must supply an expression that references a property or a function.",
                        expression.Body));
                        
        return new ExpressionDetail { MemberInfo = memberInfo, Expression = expression};
    }

}
```

Comment: Even `AssemblyQualifiedName` is not 100 % safe. You can create two distinct dynamic assemblies with the same name. (But this will be even rarer than `FullName` collision and I agree with you that that one should be already pretty rare, especially if you control the code that uses this method.)

Comment: @svick Agreed. It looks like you are a regular here, any comments on my code? Any other improvement ideas?

Comment: Your code seems reasonable to me. One note: it's annoying when I have to scroll horizontally, especially when reading comments. (This wouldn't be a problem for your code normally, but it is when you post it to SE, which shows code in a narrow window.)

Answer (score 3):

1. I think `DictionaryThing` is a really bad name for a class, you should think about a better name. And `Data()` is not a great name either. `DictionaryThing.Data` doesn't really tell you what it does.
2. I don't see any reason to use `dynamic` in your code. Using `object` instead would work just as well and it would be less confusing, because writing `dynamic` implies that you're actually doing something dynamically.
3. You could create a separate cache for each `T`. With that, you wouldn't need to compute key from the type name and you also wouldn't need the cast.

   To do this, you could create a nested static generic type, that would hold the cache. Something like:

   ```
   static class DictionaryThing 
   {
       private static CacheHolder<T>
       {
           public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<T, object>> expressionCache = …;
       }

       …
   }
   ```
4. You don't check that the `UnaryException` is actually `Convert`. I can't think of a sensible situation where it would be anything else, but I would check it anyway, just to be on the safe side.